# Multithreading and TPL do not speed up execution C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have a program that makes use of `SQL Server` to pull information from a database and then perform a series of insertions into other tables and also send an email with the data that was retireved.

The program takes around 3 and a half minutes to execute and there is only 5 rows of data in the database. I am trying to reduce this time in any way I can and have tried `multithreading` which seems to slow it down further, and `TPL` which neither increases nor reduces the time. Does anyone know why I am not seeing performance improvements?

I am using an `Intel Core i5` which I know has 2 cores so using more than 2 cores I understand will reduce performance. Here is how I am incorporating the use of tasks:

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Util util = new Util(); //Util object

        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>(); //List of Data Objects

        //Reads each row of data and creates Data obj for each   
        //Then adds each object to the list
        dataList = util.getData(); 


        var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var tasks = new Task[dataList.Count];

        int i = 0; //Count
        foreach (Data data in dataList)
        {
            //Perform insertions and send email with data
            tasks[i++] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => util.processData(data));
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks); //Wait for completion

        Console.WriteLine("DONE: {0}", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

     }
```

Util Class:

```
class Util
{
    // create and open a connection object
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("**Connection String**");

    //Gets all results from table, and adds object to list
    public List<Data> getData()
    {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("REF.GET_DATA", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //** Take data from table and assigns them to variables
                //** Removed for simplicity

                Data data= new Data(** pass varaibles here **);

                dataList.Add(data); //Add object to datalist
            }

            return dataList;
    }

    public void processData(Data data)
    {
        //** Perform range of trivial operations on data 
        //** Removed for simplicity

        byte[] results = data.RenderData(); //THIS IS WHAT TAKES A LONG TIME TO COMPLETE

        data.EmailFile(results);     

        return;


    } //END handleReport()


}
```

Am I using tasks in the wrong place? Should I instead be making use of parellelism in the `util.processData()` method? I also tried using `await` and `async` around the `util.processData(data)` call in the main method with no improvements.

EDIT:

Here is the `renderData` function:

```
//returns byte data of report results which will be attatched to email.
public byte[] RenderData(string format, string mimeType, ReportExecution.ParameterValue[] parameters)
    {
        ReportExecutionService res = new ReportExecutionService();
        res.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        res.Timeout = 600000;

        //Prepare Render arguments
        string historyID = null;
        string deviceInfo = String.Empty;
        string extension = String.Empty;
        string encoding = String.Empty;
        ReportExecution.Warning[] warnings = null;
        string[] streamIDs = null;
        byte[] results = null;


            try
            {

                res.LoadReport(reportPath, historyID);
                res.SetExecutionParameters(parameters, "en-gb"); //"/LSG Reporting/Repossession Sales (SAL)/SAL004 - Conveyancing Matter Listing"

                results = res.Render(format, deviceInfo, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIDs);
                break;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace)                
            }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: `async/await`is not meant to speed up execution, although in some cases it might. Its purpose is to provide and simplify asynchronous execution.

Comment: Hint: you have a lot of boilerplate code which could be replaced by `dataList.AsParallel().ForAll(i => util.processData(i));`

Comment: First of all, use ORM (e.g. EF) to simplify your access => right now you're a) pulling everything down then b) processing. You can process AS you pull.
Second, this largely depends on what is insider RenderData() - since you haven't provided that code it is hard to elaborate.

Comment: `//THIS IS WHAT TAKES A LONG TIME TO COMPLETE` is quite helpful, but you haven't shown us the code of that method. Without that, we can't really help you :) What version of .NET Framework are you using?

Comment: You're trying to guess where there might be inefficiency in your code. Don't. Measure where the time is going by either adding some timing measurement to your code or running it in a performance profiler.

Comment: If `RenderData` is what you measured to be taking most of your time, post the code for it.

Comment: Just a very wild shot in the dark: does the RenderData function contain any locking? (if the calls lock the same object, the threads would still have to wait on one another)

Comment: I have added the `renderData` code. I appreciate the help guys!

Comment: There are too many missing pieces to the puzzle. What is `LoadReport` doing, IO work? What does render do? And why are you using `break` when you're not inside a loop?

Comment: `ReportExecutionService ` is a class that I did not write. I am making use of it as it allows me to generate reports that I can then send as attatchements to emails. `loadReport` 'Loads a report from the Report Server catalog into a new execution' ( [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.wssux.reportingserviceswebservice.rsexecutionservice2005.reportexecutionservice.loadreport(v=sql.90).aspx) )

Comment: How many rows of data do you have?

Comment: For now, 5 rows. Execution takes around 3 and a half minutes. Eventually there will be hundreds of rows